# Secure deletion of MS Access data

Tags: windows-7, security, microsoft-access

I have tables in an Access DB  (Office 2007) which have confidential/sensitive data which needs to be removed.  The remainder of the database need to remain functional.

How do I securely remove/shred the classified data?
Does MS-Access store data outside of the .mdb file?

Comment: what [type](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/delete-one-or-more-records-from-an-access-database-HA001173951.aspx) of information are you trying to delete? records? fields? keys?

Answer (score 2):

Access doesn't store any data outside the tables unless you program it to do so.

You can delete the fields from the table or just the data. Keep in mind, any forms, reports or queries containing those fields will likely cause errors unless you also modify them. So, it might be a better choice to just delete the data.

**Be warned**, once you delete data from tables, it is gone.

Comment: Good advice. I suppose you should you shrink the database after deletion to minimize the chance of any data being left in "unused" space.

Comment: Or wipe the data from the tables, make a backup from all programs and data, secure erase the drive and copy the backup back.

Answer (score 0):

see my comment in https://superuser.com/a/545011/194578.
By the way: if you use linked tables or linked files, you data will be stored outside the mdb or accdb.

Comment: Please include the comment in the answer. Links can change or go down, which would invalidate your answer.