# Where are microsoft access tables stored?

Tags: microsoft-access

Does Access store tables and data outside of the *.mdb file ?

I have a computer which currently has a large working database on it containing some tables with confidential data.  I would like to securley delete/remove the confidential data.  Does all the data live in the *.mdb file?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer for your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all the data is in the MDB file, unless you're using ODBC or otherwise linking tables to other data sources, perhaps other MDBs.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting data and compressing the database does not guarantee that all the confidential data will be completely removed.
You should use an anonymizer to obfuscate all confidential data - and all your forms and queries will continue to work properly.
Here's an anonymizer that you get get for free:
http://www.access-experts.ch/werkzeuge_produkte/daten-anonymisierung/index.html

Good luck
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

I would say do this:

- Make a copy of the Access database.
- Then run a delete query.

This way you will always have a backup.